# Could not create scaffold in rails 4.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

[The options for rails is being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWkzY.png)

I am new to rails. I went through a tutorial and it generated a scaffold. I tried the same as shown in the picture but could not generate it.

Comment: Did you already created your project? `rails new AppName`?

Comment: I added answer below for you to follow. Your case is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

In the image that you posted, it seems that you didn't create your project first. Do this steps:

1. rails new AppName
2. After the app auto-bundled, go to your app directory and,
3. rails g scaffold Todo title:string notes:text

You can follow the following tutorial from [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)